# Is it possible to draw a black line with a colored fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art, fill

For example, in photo shop you can draw a line then select that line and contract the pixels maybe 3 pixels (depending if the line I drew was thicker)and fill that area with a color.

Thus the line has a color with a black outline.

Is it possible in illustrator to be able to do this just by simply drawing a line and having illustrator do it for you?

*completely new to illustrator*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! Use the Appearance Panel.

You can stack multiple strokes (or fills) onto the same path which is much more precise, clean, and editable than anything Photoshop can do.

[image: Appearance]

For more information on the Appearance Panel [CLICK HERE](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cs6/mastering-the-appearance-panel/).